# ssh: Could not resolve hostname i: Name or service not known

Tags: command-line, networking, server, ssh, openstack

(overcloud) [stack@nyimsp01-director-01 ~]$ source stackrc
(undercloud) [stack@nyimsp01-director-01 ~]$ for i in `openstack server list | grep "ctlplane" | awk '{print $8}' | awk -F "=" '{print $2}'`; do echo "----$i----";ssh heat-admin@i "sudo cat /etc/neutron/policy.json | grep 'create_port'";done

with this command i get the below error

ssh: Could not resolve hostname i: Name or service not known

Comment: Please provide more information, including which version of Ubuntu you are using, etc.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you are trying to do, but the error is likely because `ssh heat-admin@i` should be `ssh heat-admin@"$i"`

Comment: ssh heat-admin@"$i" yes ,its silly mistake .thank you